# Extract URL part of Text before a certain character

Tags: sql, substring, extract, charindex

I am trying to extract the hostname from these strings, i.e. everything before the first % sign.

URL before the first % sign must be extracted (the bold parts), I have tried to use MID, SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, LEFT, and LEN and just getting all muddled up.

Here are the code (at the bottom is one of my attempts).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp2;

CREATE TABLE #temp2 (url_link VARCHAR(2500));

INSERT INTO #temp2 (url_link)
VALUES
    ('az.account.box.com%2fsignup%2fcoll'),
    ('az.account.box.com%2fsignup%2fcollab%2f6kn7988x7i%3fbox_source%3dlegacy-external_collab_email%26amp%3bbox_action%3dclick_button'),
    ('app.box.com%2ffile%2f1105756887416%3fsb%3d%2factivity%2fcomments%2f515200504%26comment_id%3d515200504'),
    ('evelyn.sharefile.eu%2ff%2ffo292663-12a3-437f-8ec4-17a8f49ba4b6%3fa%3dc23e44cbd721d386'),
    ('app.box.com%2f'),
    ('app.box.com%2ffolder%2f0'),
    ('www.evernote.com%2fLogin.action');

SELECT
    url_link,
    CHARINDEX('%', url_link) AS [Pos%Char],
    LEFT(url_link, CHARINDEX('%', url_link) - 1) AS ExtractedHostname
FROM #temp2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using LEFT function to extract the substring before the % sign, but you need to subtract 1 from the length to exclude the % sign itself. Here's the corrected version of your SQL query:

```
SELECT
    url_link,
    CHARINDEX('%', url_link) AS [Pos%Char],
    LEFT(url_link, CHARINDEX('%', url_link) - 1) AS ExtractedHostname
FROM #temp2;
```